# iPhone zip files load?

Tags: objective-c

Please give me idea, How I can load a zip file to the iPhone document folder through the standard means of. I need periodically to load the zip file produced by the some Windows application. Maybe with help of iTunes?
It should work as read the zip file and update some view on my iPhone app. There is no WiFi connection or internet connection, only connection with computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable File Sharing in your app, you simply set the boolean flag “UIFileSharingEnabled” in your info.plist.

Read Ray's this post for more info  - http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app